# How to get the json file from an existing google map

Tags: json, google-maps

I need to create a custom google map search tool. So i use google map API.
I'd like to know if it's possible to get the JSON from an other map build from the native google map managment system such as this one :
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=z7YNZSDcNAU0.kviSuto4ltCY

I want my client still use the managment system he knows.

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: It's not possible to get JSON file from myMap...

Answer (score 0):

So i answer my own...
It's not possible. But in a way we can do this.
 - Download the KML
 - Use the google map geocoder to rebuild the lat & lng of all your point using the adress. (use a loop for example).